# Is there a way to stop webpacker:compile, if webpacker cache is present in a test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, gitlab, gitlab-ci, webpacker

I am trying to run some minitests in a rails app on gitlab-ci. The problem I have is I have to run `webpacker:compile` every time I run the test. This takes about 2-3 minutes on every run.

To remove the webpacker:compile step in my gitlab-ci.yml I tried to cache the folder in the cache path for the gitlab-runner which is tmp/cache/webpacker (default settings) in the webpacker.yml file.

Now, the problem I have is I want webpacker to compile if it doesn't find the cache but instead it doesn't compile and the test fails by giving me a can't find `public/packs-test/manifest.json` error.

So, is there a way to let webpacker:compile if no cache is found and stop it from compiling if a cache is found to save time ?

Here is a snippet from my `gitlab-ci.yml` and `webpacker.yml`

```
WEBPACKER.yml

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true
.
.
.
test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

  webpack_compile_output: true
```

```
GITLAB_CI.yml

cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - vendor/ruby
    - tmp/cache/assets
    - node_modules/
    - tmp/cache/webpacker/
.
.
.
Minitest:
  stage: tests
  services:
    - mysql:latest
  before_script:
    - bin/rake webpacker:compile  
  script:
    - bin/rake test TEST=test/controllers
    - bin/rake test TEST=test/helpers
    - bin/rake test TEST=test/jobs
    - bin/rake test TEST=test/mailers
    - bin/rake test TEST=test/models
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
```

I want to remove the bin/rake webpacker:compile step

Comment: To have the cache work properly for what you’re trying to do, I think you’d need to cache the public dir assets too; try caching public/packs-test. The problem would then be cache expiry. A guess: it would have to be dependent on something in version control including both yarn.lock and the digest file in tmp/cache/webpacker.

Comment: I tried caching the public/packs-test folder for the gitlab runner and then removed the `bin/rake webpacker:compile` step from the before_script. The pipeline still failed for minitest by giving me a can't find manifest.json error

Comment: If you remove the precompile step, then you would need to make sure compile: true is set for test in config/webpacker.yml and cache *after* the test run—since it would be a cold cache the first build. Without seeing what you’ve done, I can only guess, so you’d need to provide more info if you want better help.